# Good books on engineering distributed systems

Tags: distributed-computing

I am looking for a good book / blog / resources on Engineering Best Practices (developing, testing, automation, tools & deployment) for distributed systems.  Most of what I see is principle, architecture and algorithm oriented book.  Is there an engineering focussed book for distributed computing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Theo Schlossnagle's [Scalable Internet Architectures](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/067232699X)?

Comment: Yes, I have read the book  and it gave me a solid foundation on how to architecture.   But it doesn't get into the nitty gritties of, say, how to achieve code coverage or how to manage a deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://www.engbookspdf.com/

There are variety of eBooks has been empowering research development, initiating innovation, encouraging confidence, helping you preparing for your exams and career growth in the scientific field.